# Отчистить список от частично дублирующих строк

Tags: java, массивы, list

Есть список

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

он содержит порядка 10000 массивов. Каждый массив имеет длину = 20.

Есть дублирующиеся массивы в которых только 9 и 10 ячейки содержат разные значения.

Пример.

[...][...][...][...][...][...][...][...][...][aaa][111][...][...] - (1)

[...][...][...][...][...][...][...][...][...][www][bbb][...][...] - (2)

Нужно отчистить list от первого массива и оставить второй (2).

Comment: А зачем вообще так делать?) Вопрос не понятен в принципе.

Comment: ну такая ситуация складывается в работе. Есть список сотрудников у которых при переводе из одного отдел в другой некоторые характеристики меняются и нужно общий список сотрудников отчистить от полу-дубликатов. Я сделал по топорному.)) Но пришлось сделать два цикла. я подумал, что может можно как-то за один цикл это пройти.

Comment: Больше кода и подробностей добавьте в ваш вопрос.

Comment: тут нечего добавить. или сделать как то изящно или в лоб, через дополнительный список для хранения первых попавшихся дублей.

Comment: Нужно подробнее расписать критерии. Считаются дубликатами массивы, которые отличаются не более чем двумя ячейками, или массивы, которые отличаются только в 9 и 10 ячейках? Какой из дубликатов должен остаться в результате: первый попавшийся, второй или последний?

Comment: вроде это указано в условии, если внимательно читать. "только 9 и 10 ячейки", " и оставить второй (2)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

1. Сгруппировать все массивы в списки по ключу, представляющему собой массив с исключением 9 и 10 ячеек
2. Из каждой группы взять последний массив

Вариант реализации:

```
Map<String, List<String[]>> collect = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(strings -> {
            String[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(strings, strings.length);
            copy[9] = "";
            copy[10] = "";
            return Arrays.toString(copy);
        }));
List<String[]> filtered = collect.values().stream()
        .map(array -> array.get(array.size() - 1))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Стоит отметить, что реализация достаточно "прожорлива" по памяти - будет создавать много новых массивов и строк.

**UPD:** аналог с использованием Collectors.collectingAndThen

```
List<String[]> filtered = list.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(mapKey()),
        map -> map.values().stream()
                .map(array -> array.get(array.size() - 1))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
));

private static Function<String[], String> mapKey() {
    return strings -> {
        String[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(strings, strings.length);
        copy[4] = "";
        copy[5] = "";
        return Arrays.toString(copy);
    };
}
```

**UPD2:** вариант функции маппинга ключа от @Alex Chermenin:

```
private static Function<String[], String> mapKey() {
    return strings -> IntStream.range(0, strings.length)
            .filter(i -> i != 9 && i != 10)
            .mapToObj(i -> strings[i])
            .collect(Collectors.joining("_")); //"_" гарантированно нет в массиве
}
```

**UPD3:** вариант от @zRrr:

```
//Использование LinkedHashMap с access order позволит сохранить порядок элементов
Collection<String[]> filtered = list.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(mapKey2(),
                Function.identity(),
                (prev, cur) -> cur,
                () -> new LinkedHashMap<>(list.size() * 3 / 4, .75f, true)))
        .values();
```

Comment: ну я так примерно и сделал, спасибо. думал что можно как то по экономичней но видимо никак.)

Comment: Можно ещё поработать над лямбдой получения ключей группировки, например так: `strings -> IntStream.range(0, strings.length).filter(i -> i != 9 && i != 10).mapToObj(i -> strings[i]).collect(Collectors.joining("_")))`

Comment: если так делать, то лучше вместо `groupingBy` использовать `toMap` примерно: `Collectors.toMap( mapKey(), a -> a, (prev, cur) -> cur, () -> new LinkedHashMap<>( list.size() * 3 / 4, .75f, true) )`. Использование `LinkedHashMap` с access order позволит сохранить порядок элементов.